# CalandarView get user selected date

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[enter image description here][1][enter image description here][2]Hey guys I need some help I'm working on a basic calander app and I'm having some trouble retrieving a date. When I save the date it saves the current date, not the user selected date. So my question is: What is the proper way to retrieve a date from a CalandarView after it has been changed by the user? The calandarView is initialized to the current date elsewhere. I just need to grab the day month and year in a simple date format.

```
CalendarView cView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    final EditText myText = (EditText)
    final Calendar myCal = Calendar.getInstance();//initialize to current date
    myCal.setTimeInMillis(cView.getDate());//get current set date from the calandarview
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MWI5.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using CalendarView, create the following variables in your activity:

```
int day;
int month;
int year;
```

Then you can use the following listener:

```
cView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView calendarView, int year, int month, int day) {
                yourActivity.this.day = day;
                yourActivity.this.month = month;
                yourActivity.this.year = year;
            }
        });
```

then use the variables whichever way you want

**Edit (after your comment):**
Run the following example to see how it works

soActivity.java:

```
public class soActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private CalendarView cView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_so);
        cView = findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        cView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                Toast.makeText(soActivity.this, "date: "+dayOfMonth, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

and the R.layout.activity_so.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".soActivity">

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: you're getting 0 because you're setting a listener in a method that straight after goes and stores the values and then finishes. The scope of the listener finishes with the method. Try adding your calendar view in the onCreate and set the listener there, then call the method after the user selects the date to collect the final result

Comment: I added a sample activity. See how you get a new Toast with the day of the month, every time a user selects a new day